# Sprite Animations in XAML for Windows Phone 8

Tags: 2d, animation, sprites, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a 2D game for windows phone. It will feature rather simple 2D graphics and animations. I can get most things done using XAML an storyboards for animations. The performance is fine as long as the images are cached and I don't use standard user-controls (doesn't seem to work well with animations) and stick to using only canvases and images. I really like how simple it is to create basic animations using storyboards.

However, I'm not sure how far XAML and storyboards will get me. Specifically, I have no idea to do sprite-animations. Is there a way to do sprite animations in XAML?

Is it a bad idea to try create a 2D game in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on if you are using a sprite strip or separate images for each frame? Apparently if you use separate images then you could get some flickering happening, especially at load time. However if it is a sprite strip then you can implement it by modifying the Clip and RenderTransform of the source image in your DispatchTimer. Here is a website that explains:

http://www.cnblogs.com/Jax/archive/2010/02/26/1673899.html

Comment: Thanks. Been looking around and I've come to the conclusion that using sprite strip and modifying render-transform is the way to go.